# User identification claim in OpenID connect

Tags: azure-active-directory, openid-connect, auth0

I'm setting up authentication with [Auth0](http://auth0.com) and using OpenID Connect. I've set up my OWIN Startup class according to [this example](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-aspnet-owin/blob/master/examples/AspNet5-WebApp-OpenIdConnect-Sample/src/AspNet5.WebApp.OpenIdConnect/Startup.cs#L86). Now my problem is that users from the Auth0 database provide different claims than users that are authenticated by an Enterprise connection (I'm using Azure AD to test this scenario).

**My question is, which claim should I use to look up a user in my application's database to perform authorization, i.e. use as User ID?** Also note the comment in the link above, which says that I might need to "read/modify the claims that are populated based on the JWT".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenID Connect has standardized the `sub` claim for the primary user identifier. Alternatively you may be able to use the `mail` claim, with the caveat that e-mail addresses can be reassigned, and `sub` should not be.

Comment: Thanks, I found the `sub` claim in the docs now. However, for some reason, in the response I'm getting (see the example linked in the question) there is no `sub` claim on `context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity`.

Comment: in .NET you should be able to use `context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value` as a unique user identifier

Comment: That returns null, I guess this is why they set the name claim in the example. I'm gonna check with auth0, probably the problem is specific to their environment.